# Как разделить массив на две части максимально близки к равенству?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть какие то кучки камней (A1,A2,A3,A4...An) , нужно разделить масив на две части таким образом чтобы разница сумм елементов обоих частей была минимальной.

Я недавно решал задачу "Subset with given sum" используя метод о ранце, так как ваги предметов были малы, но эта задача не таааа,тут не подойдёт этот метод изза того что ограничение на вагу очень большое.

Я знаю про метод Meet-in-the-middle, но так и недопонял как ето тут применить. 
Как мне решить даную задачу с помощю метода Meet-in-the-middle?

Ограничения:

```
n = 40
A[i]<=10^8
```

Приведу еще тест:

```
5
3 4 5 6 7
```

Ответ:

```
1
```

Ну вроде так :)

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, "разница сумм", сумм элементов? и поделить массив можно "как ножницами отрезать"? или можно составлять эти две части из разных частей исходного массива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбили весь набор с суммой S пополам.

Составили все возможные подмножества первой половины - их 2^20, около миллиона - посильное количество -  посчитали и записали суммы подмножеств в массив, отсортировали его

Составили все возможные подмножества второй половины - считаем суммы s2 и по ходу ищем ближайшее к `S/2 - s2` бинарным поиском в массиве, полученном ранее  (чтобы не работать с дробными, лучше умножить на 2)

Ключевые моменты на Delphi.
`A[]` - массив данных, в `Sums[]` генерируются все возможные удвоенные суммы первой половины массива. `FindClosestIndex` бинарным поиском находит индекс значения в `Sums`, которое вкупе с текущей (удвоенной) суммой `csum` из второй половины даёт лучшее приближение к общей сумме `S`

```
  //обрабатывает первую половину массива
  procedure GenSums(ix, imax: Integer; csum: Int64);
  begin
    if ix >= imax then begin
      Sums[cnt] := csum;
      inc(cnt);
      Exit;
    end;
    GenSums(ix + 1, imax, csum);
    GenSums(ix + 1, imax, csum + Int64(2) * A[ix]);
  end;

  //обрабатывает вторую половину массива, проверяя пары с суммами первой
  procedure CheckSums(ix, imax: Integer; csum: Int64);
  var
    k: Integer;
  begin
    if ix >= imax then begin
      k := FindClosestIndex(S - csum, Sums);
      Best := Min(Best, Abs(S - (Sums[k] + csum)));
      Exit;
    end;
    CheckSums(ix + 1, imax, csum);
    CheckSums(ix + 1, imax, csum + Int64(2) * A[ix]);
  end;

Примеры выдачи:

20 40 32 83 10 32 13 57 35 
Sum=322 Diff=0
22 70 6 
Sum=98 Diff=42
86 34 74 25 28 
Sum=247 Diff=7
```

P.S. Задача не требует самих множеств, судя по образцовому ответу, иначе можно хранить пары сумма-сам набор в виде 20 битов в int32

Comment: MBo,можно еще примерчик для наглядности,я вас понял но чтобы лутче запомнить :)

Comment: Примеры дают, когда автор сам показал свой код, от которого можно отталкиваться. А запоминается куда лучше, если сам делаешь.

Comment: Если дан масив 5,8,13,27,14,сумма масива (67) (S = 67 / 2? или 67) . Разбили на две части (5,8) и (13,27,14) нашли все их суммы - (5,8,13) и (13,14,27,40,41,54).И что дальше можно еще раз пожалуйста?

Comment: Для 13 ищем ближайшее к 67/2-13=20.5 в первом, находим 13, разница 7.5. Потом к 67/2-14, тоже 13, разница 6.5. А вот  к 27 находим пары 5 и 8 с одинаковой разницей 1.5 - это лучший вариант.

Comment: Для этого теста ответ 3,я наверное не уточнил,но нам надо же все числа расходовать :-?

Comment: полтора - это половина разности. Лучше всё на 2 умножить, чтобы дробных не было. 67-13*2 ищем в удвоенном первом массиве.

Comment: Про расход чисел - мы выбираем подмножества из первой и второй половинок, которые составляют половину суммы. Оставшиеся - составляют вторую половину.

Comment: Я правильно понял,если сума не делиться нацело на два то при поиске умножать каждую сумму первого масива на 2?

Comment: Всегда умножать

Comment: Очень интересная задачка,и ее решение не знаете где можно почитать поподробнее про метод meet-in-the-middle?

Comment: [вот](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Meet-in-the-middle), например, смотрится толково и с примерами